# Solace integraion with nagios tools for monitoring

Tags: nagios

Can anyone please let me know the procedure to do the solace integration with nagios monitoring tool.
I would like to know the step that how can be monitor solace appliance with nagios core

Answer (score 0):

You can send the Solace Syslog messages to the Nagios server and do the filtration of alert at Nagios level for monitoring.

Please run the following commands on the solace appliance to log to your Nagios server.

```
solace> enable
solace# configure
solace(configure)# create syslog nagios
solace(configure/syslog)# facility command
solace(configure/syslog)# facility system
solace(configure/syslog)# facility event
solace(configure/syslog)# host 192.168.1.12 transport tcp
```

Host IP will be your destination IP, where you want syslog messages to go to.